# Sessions on Memcached in Django , the cache expire time allways 300s when i set SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 0

Tags: python, django, session, caching, python-memcached

My Django Settings.py like that:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        #'LOCATION': os.environ['MEMCACHED']
        'LOCATION': "127.0.0.1",
         #"BINARY" : True,
    },
}
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 0
```

I store my sessions on memcached. **But**, the cache expire time allway 300s!!

As django document, they say SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 0 means never timeout, but it no used for the cache timeout?

So, now i want make the session cache never timeout until browser close?

Do not tell me only set SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE, because i store the sessions in memcached, the cache has a expire time too.I want the cache never expire.

Thanks.

Comment: No people can answer me ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the reason!

There has `CACHES` in `Settings.py`.When you use memcached to store the session, and set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE=0`. Django will use the default timeout(300s) for each cache.

If u want the set the cache never timeout, you need add `TIMEOUT=0` into `CACHES`

Comment: You can set TIMEOUT to None so that, by default, cache keys never expire. A value of 0 causes keys to immediately expire (effectively “don’t cache”).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : I found this post from 2006 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/oLZTAAA6wVE
Try putting this setting in your app's settings.py.

I think you could put an expiration time very far away (like 2050 for example) and it should work. Try maybe, who knows :p.